# Commons CLI getValue() and getOptionValue()

Tags: java, command-line-interface, flags, apache-commons-cli

I'm a bit puzzled about the two methods. When I use `getOptionValue(optionName)` I do get the argument that I had entered in the command line but I get null when I use `optionName.getValue()`

getValue()

> Returns the specified value of this Option or null if there is no
>   value.

getOptionValue(String)

> Retrieve the first argument, if any, of this option.

As you can see `getOptionValue(String)` explicitly says argument where as the other only says value but they both have "value" in their method name. Since there is no `setValue(String)` method or something of such, I just assumed it's just the same as argument.

```
public static void main(final String[] args ) {
    CommandLine cmd = null;
    Option program = Option.builder("p")
             .hasArg()
             .required(true)
             .longOpt("program")
             .build();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption( program );

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    try {
        cmd = parser.parse( options, args );
    }
    catch( ParseException exp ) {
        System.err.println( "Parsing failed.  Reason: " + exp.getMessage() );
    }

    String[] list;
    list = cmd.getArgs();

    int argsN = program.getArgs();
    String optionValue = cmd.getOptionValue("p");
    String value = program.getValue();

    System.out.println(argsN);
    System.out.println(optionValue);
    System.out.println(value);

}
```

Output is:

1

[arg]

null

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but this seems to be on-purpose currently. In the class [DefaultParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/cli/DefaultParser.html) in method `handleOption()` at line `601` the code does:

```
option = (Option) option.clone();
```

Which specifically cuts ties between the option you pass in and the internal option object, it seems the code does not want to change the objects that it was given in any way.

So the only way of retrieving the values is via the `CommandLine` class.